# Android my app permission

Tags: android

I created 2 simple projects.
In the first I put the permission to manifest:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.MODULE"
            android:label="Example module"
            android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:exported="true"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true">
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="com.example.graph.SHOW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And in the second project:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.MODULE" /
```

But If I remove uses-permission from the second project, and then start activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.graph.SHOW"))
```

of first project - it's still starting. But why? How is it starting without permission? How to correctly protect my second project using permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need permission to start a application. You can run all apps without asking permissions to the developers. For instance I can run this code (wich starts a famous Barcode Scanner) without asking the developer.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", output);
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "QR_CODE");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_SHOW_CONTENTS", false);
```

Comment: To add to your answer, the OP's first project has exported the Activity by adding the `intent-filter`:`<action android:name="com.example.graph.SHOW"/>`. This allows **any** app to launch the Activity.

Comment: Can I restrict any apps? I want to allow launch my activity only for apps that have some "password"/permission...

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html